# PostgreSQL sometimes fails to detect serialization failures

Tags: postgresql, transaction, concurrency, isolation-level

I have an http-server in application language that looks roughly like this:

```
item = SELECT item FROM table WHERE field = 'value'
if (item) {
  UPDATE another field on item
} else {
  INSERT item VALUE field = 'value' and so on
}
```

The field has unique constraint. About once every several minutes **two** requests with the same `value` come in at the same time. They both execute this same code so of course there is a race condition. I decided that if I wrap it in a transaction with SERIALIZABLE isolation level and retry on every serialization failure then the problem is solved. And on localhost it worked fine. I indeed see serialization failures thrown with error code 40001 as expected.

*However* on production in a database under load for some reason a `Unique constraint violation` is sporadically thrown with a code of 23505. It only happens sometimes. I put a lot of effort to  reproduce it on localhost but failed. Everytime I get a normal 40001. I tried to run server code in separate processes and to put delays at different points to enforce certain orders of execution. It only happens on production. So I added extensive logging to prod. The logs say that every time when a problem occurs the `item` is not found at first but when INSERT happens it triggers `Unique constraint violation`. So it looks just ad a race condition.

But why sometimes under some conditions Postgres SERIALIZABLE transactions don't detect it as they should? Or how to debug it? It happens like several times in a day out of several dozens of cases.

The (almost) exact SQL look like this:
(I omitted detailed fields lists and exact parameters)

```sql
START TRANSACTION
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE product_code = $1
LIMIT 1 -- product_code is a parameter

SELECT *
FROM licenses
WHERE license_key = $1
LIMIT 1 -- license_key is another and it's unique across the table
-- At this point SELECT did not return anything but it was inserted before this INSERT by exactly the same transaction

INSERT INTO licenses ("license_key", "product_id", "other_data",...)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3,...) RETURNING "id"
query failed: error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "licenses_license_key_key"
```

Comment: Can we have the exact statements? The ones you show are syntactically incorrect.

Comment: It's possible that you've run into [this problem](http://jepsen.io/analyses/postgresql-12.3), which will be fixed in 12.4 (and 11.9, 10.14 etc.).

Comment: Try with a single INSERT … ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE … RETURNING … command.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I added them.

Comment: @CL. I need a correct sum of data from both requests, not just data of one of them. This is the first time I change isolation levels in transactions and actually think about them in my entire career of 7 years. This is a huge disappoint.

Comment: So far, I have seen nothing that would prevent using a single command; the product data lookup could be done with a subquery in the INSERT. Can you tell us where exactly the parameters in the INSERT come from; are they `products` values?

Comment: @CL. The most important column is exiration date. A request has to either create a license N hours long or make it N hours longer. So if we got a +2 hours request and a +3 hours request then the length should equal 5 in the end.

Comment: Strange. Two ideas: 1) there are concurrent transactions with a different isolation level. 2) [This bug](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/db7b729d-0226-d162-a126-8a8ab2dc4443%40jepsen.io) that was recently discussed on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this in a serialized transaction should work, unless there is [a bug](http://jepsen.io/analyses/postgresql-12.3).

As a workaround, use this command, which tries to add a new license; if the license key already exists, it adds the new hours to the existing value:

```
INSERT INTO licenses(license_key, product_id, hours)
VALUES ($1,
        (SELECT product_id FROM products WHERE product_code = $2 LIMIT 1),
        $3)
ON CONFLICT (license_key) DO UPDATE
SET hours = hours + EXCLUDED.hours
RETURNING id;
```

<sup>[documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. However I think an answer should be "why it's happeining" rather than "how to find a workaround". Maybe add that link to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

This comment/answer was sent to me by Thomas Munro:

> My guess is that they might have multiple unique indexes, and might
> have run into [this problem](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAGPCyEZG76zjv7S31v_xPeLNRuzj-m%3DY2GOY7PEzu7vhB%3DyQog%40mail.gmail.com).
>
> **Summary:**  It used to be that we always reported unique constraint violations (UCV) before detecting
> SSI failures, with the idea being that errors don't matter; SSI only
> makes promises about the transactions that commit.  Then we added a
> one line tweak that makes it try to detect an SSI failure just before
> it raises a UCV (think of it as an error priority: IMHO SSI errors
> need higher priority because automatic transaction retry systems need
> reliable SSI errors; what are they supposed to do with UCV?).  But now
> we know that that wasn't quite good enough.  As described in that
> thread, before reporting UCV we probably need to run around and find
> *all* the indexes you'll insert into, to give them a chance to check
> for SSI errors, before we report UCV.  In the case that was reported
> in that -bugs thread, you could change the outcome by changing the
> order that UNIQUE constraints were defined.  Ugh.  That'll require a
> bit of an architectural redesign, possibly including a new index AM
> entry function, but I think it's worth it (and if done right, it can
> also allow for SSI errors to have higher priority than exclusion
> constraint errors).

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I have 3 unique indexes on that table including PK. This also seems plausable. I don't know which of the two bugs it is.